# Validate user in UIAlertAction in swift

Tags: ios, swift

it is me again.  I am having an issue with a simple password validation in a UIAlertAction.  This is the goal of my application, in a TableView when the user slide right it will be presented with 2 options, 1.-) for Edit the record and 2.) For delete the record.

When the user selects edit, the application needs to validate if the record (what I call "Folder") has a password or not.  If it has a password it will prompt the user to insert the password.  If the password is correct the UIAlertAction should display the next View; if the password is incorrect I want to display an error message saying the password was incorrect and the screen should not change.

Here is the code of my View Controller :

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FoldersListViewController: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var myFoldersTableView: UITableView!
    var context: NSManagedObjectContext!
    // public property that represent an array of all folders created by an user in the application.
    var folders: [Folder] = []

    // public property that will allow to set the context that will be use to save the data.


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
        self.loadFolders()

        if(folders.count == 0){
            loadTestData()
            myFoldersTableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return folders.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: cellFolder = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellFolder", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellFolder

        let folder = folders[indexPath.row]

        if(folder.picture.length > 0){
            var newSize:CGSize = CGSize(width: 64,height: 64)
            let rect = CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height)
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0.0)
            var photo =  UIImage(data: folder.picture)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)

            photo!.drawInRect(rect)
            let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            cell.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
            cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
            cell.imageView?.image = newImage

        }

        cell.labelFolderName.text = folder.name

        return cell
    }



    // Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
        return true
    }

    func loadFolders() {
        var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Folder")
        let handler = HACoreDataHandler()
        context = handler.context
        var error: NSError?

        folders = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [Folder]

        if(error != nil){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
            }

            alert.addAction(dismiss)
            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }


    }

    func loadTestData(){
        var tmpFolder = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Folder", inManagedObjectContext: context!) as! Folder
        tmpFolder.name = "Erika Velez"
        let tmpPhoto = UIImage(named: "ErikaVelez")
        tmpFolder.picture = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tmpPhoto, 1)
        tmpFolder.isprotected = false

        folders.append(tmpFolder)

        var error: NSError?

        context?.save(&error)

        if(error != nil){
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                Void in
            }

            alert.addAction(dismiss)

            presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        self.loadFolders()
        myFoldersTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            // Delete the row from the data source
            var item = folders[indexPath.row] as Folder

            folders.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context?.deleteObject(item)

            var error: NSError?

            context?.save(&error)

            if(error != nil){

                let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                    Void in
                }

                alert.addAction(dismiss)

                presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            self.myFoldersTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
        var delete = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (action:UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath:NSIndexPath!) -> Void in


            var folder = self.folders[indexPath.row] as Folder

            var handler = HACoreDataHandler()
            var error: NSError?

            self.folders.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            handler.context?.deleteObject(folder)

            handler.context?.save(&error)

            self.myFoldersTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)

        }

        delete.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        var details = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Edit") { (action: UITableViewRowAction!, indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Void in
            let tmpFolder = self.folders[indexPath.row] as Folder

            let destination = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("editFolder") as! EditFolderViewController

            destination.folder = tmpFolder

            let navigationController = self.parentViewController as! UINavigationController

            var response:  Bool = true

            if( tmpFolder.isprotected == true){
                var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Password Validation", message: "Please enter the folder password", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
                alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
                    textField.text = ""
                })

                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                    let textField = alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
                    if (tmpFolder.password == textField.text){
                        response  =  true
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("listOcassions", sender: self)
                    } else {
                        let wrongPasswordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                            Void in
                        }

                        wrongPasswordAlert.addAction(dismiss)

                        self.presentViewController(wrongPasswordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        response  = false

                    } // else if (folder.password == textField.text)

                }))
            }
            if(response){
                navigationController.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
            }
            //navigationController.presentViewController(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
            //self.showDetailViewController(destination, sender: self)

        }

        details.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        return [delete,details]

    }


    // Override to support rearranging the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var tmpFolder = folders[fromIndexPath.row]
        folders.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
        folders.insert(tmpFolder, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
    }



    // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if(segue.identifier=="listOcassions"){
            let ocassions = segue.destinationViewController as! DatesViewController
            var path = myFoldersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
            var folder = folders[path!.row]
            ocassions.folder = folder
        }
    }

    override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
        var response: Bool = true

        if let ident = identifier{
            if ident == "listOcassions" {
                let path = myFoldersTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
                var folder = folders[path!.row]

                if( folder.isprotected == true){
                    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Password Validation", message: "Please enter the folder password", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
                    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
                        textField.text = ""
                    })

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Login", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                        let textField = alert.textFields![0] as! UITextField
                        if (folder.password == textField.text){
                            response  =  true
                              self.performSegueWithIdentifier("listOcassions", sender: self)
                        } else {
                            let wrongPasswordAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Invalid password.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                            var dismiss = UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .Default) { (alertAction: UIAlertAction!) ->
                                Void in
                            }

                            wrongPasswordAlert.addAction(dismiss)

                            self.presentViewController(wrongPasswordAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            response  = false

                        } // else if (folder.password == textField.text)

                    }))

                    // 4. Present the alert.
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } //if folder.isprotected == true

            }
        }
        return response
    }


}
```

Here is the highlighted code that I put in place but it is not working.  Any help is appreciated a lot.

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Julio.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"?

Comment: what is the probelem ?

Comment: You don't seem to present the alert controller anywhere.

Comment: Hi, when I say "it is not working" I mean the validation is not happening because if you check this line here is where I am trying to present the alert

Comment: Hi Paulw11, sorry i miss that line, but even with that, the screen still loads without waiting for the password validation